# How to match words with combination of letters and numbers but avoid words with only numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a RegEx that can get me the PO BOX full information from a string, I figured that I need to get and then everything else up to the point where a full string of numbers is found (the po box number is ok, **after that**, only if a word is a combination of numbers and letters is ok to match, if the whole word is made out of numbers then it should stop there i.e.

From the following string:

```
"Po Box 321 Stn Commerce Court 123 Sample St"
```

I need to get everything before *123 Sample St*, like this:

```
"Po Box 321 Stn Commerce Court "
```

From the following string:

```
"PO Box 456 Stn 1st Can Place"
```

I need to get everything because there is no word made out of only numbers after the PO Box number

So far I achieve to get the first case working, but I haven't yet find an expression that works for both strings,

My attempt:

```
Regex.Match(txtString.Text, @"PO BOX [0-9]+([\s\w][^0-9]*|\s[a-zA-Z0-9]\s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive look ahead :

```
PO BOX [0-9]+.*(?= \d+|$)
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/bK7nY2/1

Or use a negative look ahead :

```
PO BOX [0-9]+((?!\d+ ).)*
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/bK7nY2/3

Comment: Thank you Kasramvd, I not sure why though I don't get the same result in C# using your suggestion, My code is like this: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(txtString.Text, @"PO BOX [0-9]+.*(?= \d+|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            txtResult.Text = match.Success ? match.Value : @"No-matched";
        }

Comment: @pcons Did you got any error? what was your output?

Comment: It works out for "PO Box 234 Stn 1st Can Place" -it retrieves everything which is good-, however for the string "Po Box 442 Stn Commerce Court 199 Bay St" it also retrieves everything, it doesn't stop at 199...

Comment: @pcons What about `PO BOX [0-9]+((?!\d+).)*`?

Comment: I get the opposite, it works for "Po Box 442 Stn Commerce Court 199 Bay St" by retrieving just "Po Box 442 Stn Commerce Court 199 Bay St" but now it does not work for "PO Box 234 Stn 1st Can Place" because it just retrieves "PO Box 234 Stn"

Comment: @pcons OK, so just add a space after `\d+`